# How to create a form for reviewing user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I would like to implement a user review based on Hartl's tutorial.

I have no problem doing it inside Rails' console but I am having trouble with the forms.

The form is able to save but doesn't save the content:

```
INSERT INTO "reviews" ("reviewer_id", "reviewee_id", "created_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["reviewer_id", 1], ["reviewee_id", 15], ["created_at", 2016-09-16 09:52:49 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-09-16 09:52:49 UTC]]
```

This is the User model:

```
has_many :active_reviews,   class_name: "Review",
                          foreign_key:"reviewer_id",
                          dependent: :destroy
has_many :passive_reviews,  class_name: "Review",
                          foreign_key:"reviewee_id",
                          dependent: :destroy
has_many :reviewing, through: :active_reviews, source: :reviewee
has_many :reviewers,  through: :passive_reviews, source: :reviewer

def review(other_user, great)
  active_reviews.create!(reviewee_id: other_user.id, content: great)
end
```

And the Review model:

```
belongs_to :reviewer, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :reviewee, class_name: "User"
validates :reviewer_id, presence: true
validates :reviewee_id, presence: true
```

And the Review controller:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]


  def create
    @review = current_user.active_reviews.build
    @user = User.find(params[:reviewee_id])
    current_user.review(@user, :content)
    redirect_to reviews_user_path(@user)
    flash[:success] = "User reviewed"
  end

  def destroy
  end

end
```

Views (shared/_review_form.html.erb):

```
<%= form_for(@review) do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
        <div><%= hidden_field_tag :reviewee_id, @user.id %></div>
        <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Leave a review..." %>
                    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Views (users/user_reviews.html.erb):

```
<% provide(:title, @title) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="col-md-4">
    <section class="user_info">
      <%= gravatar_for @user %>
      <h1><%= @user.name %></h1>
      <span><%= link_to "view my profile", @user %></span>
      <span><b>Microposts:</b> <%= @user.microposts.count %></span>
    </section>
    <section class="user_info">
      <%= render 'shared/review_form' %>
    </section>
    <% @reviews.each do |r| %>
    <ol class="users follow">
      <li><%= r.reviewer.name %>: <%= r.content %></li>
    </ol>
  <% end %>
 </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd recommend reading [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). It'll help you understand how to deal with sites such as Stack Overflow. We're not concerned about your expertise or experience, we want to see well thought-out questions that are asked well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have not called the 'save' method in your create function

Eg:

```
def create

    #---your code----

    @reviews= Review.new(review_params)

    if @review.save
        redirect_to :action => 'list'
    else      
        render :action => 'new'
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks i have figured it out

My content was not inserted because it was an hash inside review

```
"review"=>{"content"=>"fsdfsdfsdf"}
```

solution was

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:reviewee_id])
  @review = Review.create!(reviewer_id: current_user.id, reviewee_id:@user.id, content: params[:review][:content])
if @review.save
  redirect_to reviews_user_path(@user)
  flash[:success] = "User reviewed"
 end
end

def destroy
end
```

Comment: Please don't add answers to your question unless you intend to select this as the official answer. Instead, thank the answerers who helped you the most by upvoting their answers and/or selecting the one that provided the solution. Adding your final code doesn't accomplish that and is actually discouraged.

Comment: Thanks, i shall take note.